# How to create separate tables by another variable

Tags: r

Ok so I want to create a simple 2x2 table and then analyse this via a chi-square distribution

> Variable A: 2 levels
>
> Variable B: 2 levels

Easy enough. But I want to create 4 separate tables based on a third variable

Variable C: 4 levels

I know I can split the data into 4 separate data-files and do this but is there a simpler way to do this, and do so in a way that it creates 4 tables that I can then perform a chi-square analysis on?

```
Conservatives <- table(Data$Belief, Data$Group)[Data$Party=1]
```

Edit: Found the solution

```
with(Data,by(cbind(Belief,Group),list(factor(Party)),table))
with(Data,by(cbind(Belief,Group),list(factor(Party)),function(x){
chisq.test(table(x))
}))

H2 <- table(Data$Belief, Data$Group, Data$Party)
prop.table(H2, c(2,3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using mtcars data frame, the result is stored in a list

```
with(mtcars,by(cbind(mpg,cyl),list(factor(vs)),table))
```

**Edit:** storing the result is as simple as specifying a variable name in front. Same goes for the test, you can loop through the list and apply the test, or alternatively

```
with(mtcars,by(cbind(mpg,cyl),list(factor(vs)),function(x){
  chisq.test(table(x))
}))
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but that doesn't appear to store it as separate tables to then do a chi-square analysis on it

Comment: Thanks that certainly helps, now just to find out how to do a prop.table on it as well!

Comment: @ASoutter Just replace chisq.test by prop.table! `prop.table(table(x))`

Comment: that then gives a proportion table with two columns for every single participants. Rather than a simple 2x2, and if you try and specify margins = 2, responds with the error Error in prop.table(, margins = 2) : unused argument (margins = 2)

Comment: @ASoutter Without some data it is hard to tell, the argument is margin without s.

Comment: Tried it with margin and it just shouts back Error in prop.test(x, margin = 2) : unused argument (margin = 2)

Comment: @ASoutter Well then you are proverbially screwed. Ask another question with details.

Comment: Nevermind @user2974951 found the solution. It's prop.table(x, c(2,3))